# Node.js Error, regarding everything about it really

Tags: javascript, node.js

Every time my team tries to implement something in node.js, this is what happens, any ideas as to how we should go about fixing it? - note that we are new to node

```
$ npm install express --save

 SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Object.exports.createScript (vm.js:24:10)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:235:25)
    at bound (domain.js:287:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:300:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:427:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:95:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:182:7)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:211:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:550:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:827:14)
```

Answer (score 6):

You're not supposed to type `npm` commands into the Node REPL. That's for typing JavaScript into.

Type the `npm` commands directly into your shell.

Oh, and you're not supposed to type the `$` either. That just represents the common shell prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Just type into your Command Prompt (cmd).

```
npm install express --save
```